Headless distribution update of Xubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to update Xubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS on my headless server without success.
What I've tried:

I installed update-manager to be able to upgrade to 24.04 (as stated on the Xubuntu website) using Remmina / XRDP. However, when executing update-manager -c -d, I do get a message telling me that there's a newer version of Xubuntu, but when clicking "Update...", I'm being thrown out the application with an error message that says Error executing command as another user: Not authorized despite having typed my sudo password after application start.
When executing sudo update-manager -c -d, I'm getting a warning Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display: :10.0 and the application exits.

So I tried a pure-cli approach:

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
sudo vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts
sudo do-release-upgrade will just tell me that there's no development version of an LTS available.

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Also asked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518533/xubuntu-headless-distribution-upgrade    Have you checked your calendar and the current date; we've not yet reached 15 August 2024 which was the scheduled date for release of 24.04.1 which had to occur first (before the upgrade from prior LTS or 22.04 would open).  Refer release notes or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518533/xubuntu-headless-distribution-upgrade
